# handling events on drop downlist change in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892066/knockoutjs-click-event-invoked-on-every-option-in-select) of drop down change event and tried but could not get it to work.. Would appreciate some help..

My html:

```
<div data-bind="with: g">

            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: gname" /></div>

            <div>
                <table>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-bind="with:gdetails">
                            <td>
                                <select data-bind="options: eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value:eventschemacondition().schema, event: {change: setschema}"></select>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

My javascript:

```
 var eventschemas = [{ "schema": "Test" }, { "schema": "Another Test" }];

        var AppScope = function () {
            function EventSchemaCondition(data) {
                this.schema = ko.observable(data.schema);

                this.setschema = function () {
                    console.log("event fired");

                };
            }

            function Gdetails(data) {
                this.eventschemacondition = ko.observable(data.eventschemacondition);
            }

            function G(data) {
                this.gname = ko.observable(data.gname);
                this.gdetails = ko.observable(data.gdetails);
            }

            function GsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.g = ko.observable(
                new G({
                    gname: "",
                    gdetails: new Gdetails({ eventschemacondition: new EventSchemaCondition({ schema: "" }) })
                }));
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new GsViewModel());
        }();
```

The error I receive :

Message: Unable to process binding "event: function (){return {change:setschema} }"

Message: setschema is not defined

Thanks

Comment: try `event: {change: $data.setschema}`

Comment: yes besrtums `$data` should be there which specifies it refers to current vm .

Comment: @Beartums Error goes away but I do not see 'event fired' message in console log

Comment: simple add `eventschemacondition().setschema` it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a simple change you just need to set `setschema` like this `eventschemacondition().setschema` because `setschema` is not directly under `getdetails` .

**View :**

```
 <select data-bind="options: eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value:eventschemacondition().schema, event: {change:eventschemacondition().setschema}"></select>
```

Working Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22105/)